# Join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 tables. First one is a list of personnel:

Table `PersonnelId_personnel         Name
1                    John
2                    Alice
3                    Tom
4                    Charles
5                    Ben`

Table `Department`

```
Id_personnel         Department
1                    Department 1
2                    Department 2
3                    Department 3
4                    Department 4
5                    Department 5
```

and table with medical leave:

Table `Medical`

```
Id_personnel         Start_date         End_date
1                    2012-08-02         2012-08-05
2                    2012-08-02         2012-08-15
3                    2012-10-04         2012-10-06
4                    2012-10-04         2012-10-06
5                    2012-09-20         2012-09-21
```

For a given date (let's say 2012-10-05) I want to have something like

```
Department 1                    John
Department 2                    Alice
Department 3                    Tom             2012-10-04         2012-10-06
Department 4                    Charles         2012-10-04         2012-10-06
Department 5                    Ben
```

Using INNER JOIN I am able to get only those sick. I have something like this:

```
    SELECT a.Name, b.Department, c.Start_date, c.End_date FROM Personnel a
      INNER JOIN Department b ON a.Id_personnel = b.Id_personnel
      INNER JOIN Medical c ON a.Id_personnel = c.Id_personnel
   WHERE c.Start_date <= 2012-10-05  AND c.End_date >= 2012-10-05
```

And the obvious wrong result is:

```
Department 3                    Tom             2012-10-04         2012-10-06
Department 4                    Charles         2012-10-04         2012-10-06
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give conditions in `CASE` Statement instead of `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Department,
  CASE WHEN c.Start_date <= '2012-10-05' AND c.End_date >= '2012-10-05' 
       THEN c.Start_date ELSE '' END AS Start_date
 ,CASE WHEN c.Start_date <= '2012-10-05' AND c.End_date >= '2012-10-05'
       THEN c.End_date ELSE '' END AS END_date
  FROM Personnel a
  JOIN Department b ON a.Id_personnel = b.Id_personnel
  JOIN Medical c ON a.Id_personnel = c.Id_personnel
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baa28e/1)

#### UPDATE <sup>(from comments)</sup>

If you don't want to repeat the same person for same department you need to group them like this:

```
GROUP BY a.Id_personnel,Department
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1834/2)

#### UPDATE 2

You need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function when the same person has more than one leave:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Name, b.Department,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN c.Start_date <= '2012-10-05' 
                     AND c.End_date >= '2012-10-05' 
               THEN c.Start_date ELSE '' END SEPARATOR ' ') AS Start_date
 ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN c.Start_date <= '2012-10-05' 
                     AND c.End_date >= '2012-10-05'
               THEN c.End_date ELSE '' END SEPARATOR '') AS END_date
  FROM Personnel a
  JOIN Department b ON a.Id_personnel = b.Id_personnel
  JOIN Medical c ON a.Id_personnel = c.Id_personnel
 GROUP BY a.Id_personnel,Department
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa88e/21)

Comment: Ohhh... so close. But still need something! In Table Medical I have and other records. Some have medical leave in March, August and so on. Unfortunately they all are selected, yes without dates... but still there.

Comment: @MugurUngureanu Can you show the sample data in [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/147ab/14)

Comment: OK. I just added one record, but I have a lot more. It is more clear now? I am sorry for my English.

Comment: @MugurUngureanu Please give that link

Comment: I don't know how. But just duplicate the first record from Medical and change the Start_date and End_date. The guy with the Id_personnel=1 has 2 medical leave.

Comment: @MugurUngureanu So you don't want duplicate records. Right?

Comment: Remember please that even those with Medical leave in that specific day they still had some medical leave in another days.

Comment: Just add  `GROUP BY a.Id_personnel,Department` see [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1834/1)

Comment: I tried that. But if Charles has another medical leave I will not get the date. I just changed the Id_personnel value on line 45 from 3 to 4. And Tom even it was on medical leave it get no dates in your example using GROUP BY. Like here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa88e/1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT a.Name, b.Department, c.Start_date, c.End_date
      FROM Personnel a
      Left JOIN Department b ON a.Id_personnel = b.Id_personnel
      Left JOIN Medical c ON a.Id_personnel = c.Id_personnel
   WHERE c.Start_date <= 2012-10-05  AND c.End_date >= 2012-10-05
```

Comment: I get only those on medical leave. I must say that in the Table Medical are a important number of records. I only want to know who are at work and who aren't in a particular day.